# python - check if permutation exists/combination is unique

Tags: python, list, unique, permutation

I have the following code which creates combinations of fruits, veggies, and drinks that falls within a certain price range:

```
fruits = [('apple', 1), ('banana', 2), ('orange', 3)]
veggies = [('tomato', 1), ('cucumber', 2), ('onion', 3)]
drinks = [('water', 1), ('juice', 2), ('soda', 3)]

for fruit1 in fruits:
    for fruit2 in fruits:
        for veggie1 in veggies:
            for veggie2 in veggies:
                for drink1 in drinks:
                    for drink2 in drinks:
                        if 12 <= fruit1[1]+fruit2[1]+veggie1[1]+veggie2[1]+drink1[1]+drink2[1] <= 14: 
                            if fruit1 != fruit2: 
                                if veggie1 != veggie2: 
                                    if drink1 != drink2:
                                        combos.append((fruit1[0], fruit2[0], veggie1[0], veggie2[0], drink1[0], drink2[0], fruit1[1]+fruit2[1]+veggie1[1]+veggie2[1]+drink1[1]+drink2[1]))
```

It checks to make sure it doesn't pick the same fruit/veggie/drink twice but I need to make sure the combinations are unique.

For example, if I end up with

```
('apple', 'banana', 'tomato', 'cucumber', 'water', 'soda', 10)
```

I don't also want

```
('banana', 'apple', 'tomato', 'cucumber', 'water', 'soda', 10)
```

and so on. This is giving me more trouble than it should so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Atleast two of all the categories should be used?

Comment: `if 12 <= fruit1[1]+fruit2[1]+veggie1[1]+veggie2[1]+drink1[1]+drink2[1] <= 14:`... invalid syntax!

Comment: @isedev, It is a valid syntax. `a <= b <= c` is equivalent to `a <= b and b <= c`. (chained operators)

Comment: well I'll be... new one on me, at least I've learned something new today.

Comment: Holy nesting indeed. I think it's best to avoid all of that nesting by using the modules designed for it, i.e.: itertools.

Comment: I will be using itertools, thanks all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can process the data like this

```
prices = {k:v for items in [fruits, veggies, drinks] for k, v in items}
fru,veg,dri=[i[0] for i in fruits],[i[0] for i in veggies],[i[0] for i in drinks]

from itertools import combinations, product, chain
for items in product(*(combinations(i, r = 2) for i in (fru, veg, dri))):
    total = sum(prices[i] for item in items for i in item)
    if 12 <= total <= 14:
        print tuple(chain.from_iterable(items)) + (total,)
```

**Output**

```
('apple', 'banana', 'tomato', 'onion', 'juice', 'soda', 12)
('apple', 'banana', 'cucumber', 'onion', 'water', 'soda', 12)
('apple', 'banana', 'cucumber', 'onion', 'juice', 'soda', 13)
('apple', 'orange', 'tomato', 'cucumber', 'juice', 'soda', 12)
('apple', 'orange', 'tomato', 'onion', 'water', 'soda', 12)
('apple', 'orange', 'tomato', 'onion', 'juice', 'soda', 13)
('apple', 'orange', 'cucumber', 'onion', 'water', 'juice', 12)
('apple', 'orange', 'cucumber', 'onion', 'water', 'soda', 13)
('apple', 'orange', 'cucumber', 'onion', 'juice', 'soda', 14)
('banana', 'orange', 'tomato', 'cucumber', 'water', 'soda', 12)
('banana', 'orange', 'tomato', 'cucumber', 'juice', 'soda', 13)
('banana', 'orange', 'tomato', 'onion', 'water', 'juice', 12)
('banana', 'orange', 'tomato', 'onion', 'water', 'soda', 13)
('banana', 'orange', 'tomato', 'onion', 'juice', 'soda', 14)
('banana', 'orange', 'cucumber', 'onion', 'water', 'juice', 13)
('banana', 'orange', 'cucumber', 'onion', 'water', 'soda', 14)
```

If you want to pick only one element in `drinks` then you can change the combinations part like this

```
d = {0: 2, 1: 2, 2: 1}
for items in product(*(combinations(j, r=d.get(i)) for i, j in enumerate((fru,veg,dri)))):
```

With that change, the output becomes

```
('apple', 'orange', 'cucumber', 'onion', 'soda', 12)
('banana', 'orange', 'tomato', 'onion', 'soda', 12)
('banana', 'orange', 'cucumber', 'onion', 'juice', 12)
('banana', 'orange', 'cucumber', 'onion', 'soda', 13)
```

Comment: This looks like it works but I am not familiar with itertools so I will have to research it. Can you explain the first part to me -> prices = {k:v for items in [fruits, veggies, drinks] for k, v in items}

What would I need to change if I only wanted one drink item?

Comment: That particular part within `{..}` is called dictionary comprehension, which stores the price of each item against its name. You can try to `print prices`.

Comment: Thanks. And if I wanted 2 fruits and 2 veggies, but only 1 drink? Is there an easy way to do that? I see you have combinations(i, r = 2) which is telling it two items for each in (fru, veg, dri). And lastly, why the comma after + (total,) at the end. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

### Eliminate redundant sets after creation:

You can make a set of frozensets, which will eliminate redundant sets:

```
>>> tup_1 = ('apple', 'banana', 'tomato', 'cucumber', 'water', 'soda', 10)
>>> tup_2 = ('banana', 'apple', 'tomato', 'cucumber', 'water', 'soda', 10)
>>> fs_1 = frozenset(tup_1)
>>> fs_2 = frozenset(tup_2)
>>> set([fs_1, fs_2])
set([frozenset(['tomato', 'apple', 10, 'water', 'cucumber', 'soda', 'banana'])])
```

You need a `frozenset` for each item because [elements of a `set` must be hashable](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset). Keep in mind you lose ordering with this method.

### Ensure no redundancy prior:

Also, itertools.combinations will ensure that you don't get redundant items:

```
import itertools
fruits = [('apple', 1), ('banana', 2), ('orange', 3)]
veggies = [('tomato', 1), ('cucumber', 2), ('onion', 3)]
drinks = [('water', 1), ('juice', 2), ('soda', 3)]
combs=(itertools.combinations(fruits, 2), 
       itertools.combinations(veggies, 2), 
       itertools.combinations(drinks, 2))
multi_combs = [list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(i)) 
                    for i in itertools.product(*combs)]

print(len(multi_combs))
```

prints

```
27
```

And then you can filter:

```
filtered_combs = [i for i in multi_combs 
                      if 12 <= sum(p for _, p in  i) <= 14]
```

and

```
len(filtered_combs)
```

is

```
16
```

### Results:

And to pretty print the items, with the sums:

```
printable = [list(itertools.chain((j for j, _ in i), 
                                  [sum(p for _, p in  i),])) 
                                      for i in filtered_combs]

pprint.pprint(printable)
```

prints

```
[['apple', 'banana', 'tomato', 'onion', 'juice', 'soda', 12],
 ['apple', 'banana', 'cucumber', 'onion', 'water', 'soda', 12],
 ['apple', 'banana', 'cucumber', 'onion', 'juice', 'soda', 13],
 ['apple', 'orange', 'tomato', 'cucumber', 'juice', 'soda', 12],
 ['apple', 'orange', 'tomato', 'onion', 'water', 'soda', 12],
 ['apple', 'orange', 'tomato', 'onion', 'juice', 'soda', 13],
 ['apple', 'orange', 'cucumber', 'onion', 'water', 'juice', 12],
 ['apple', 'orange', 'cucumber', 'onion', 'water', 'soda', 13],
 ['apple', 'orange', 'cucumber', 'onion', 'juice', 'soda', 14],
 ['banana', 'orange', 'tomato', 'cucumber', 'water', 'soda', 12],
 ['banana', 'orange', 'tomato', 'cucumber', 'juice', 'soda', 13],
 ['banana', 'orange', 'tomato', 'onion', 'water', 'juice', 12],
 ['banana', 'orange', 'tomato', 'onion', 'water', 'soda', 13],
 ['banana', 'orange', 'tomato', 'onion', 'juice', 'soda', 14],
 ['banana', 'orange', 'cucumber', 'onion', 'water', 'juice', 13],
 ['banana', 'orange', 'cucumber', 'onion', 'water', 'soda', 14]]
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't that efficient a way to do it, because once you've spent more than 14 units you don't need to keep searching.  But you can use `itertools` to simplify -- or at least flatten -- the brute force approach:

```
from itertools import combinations, product, chain

fruits = [('apple', 1), ('banana', 2), ('orange', 3)]
veggies = [('tomato', 1), ('cucumber', 2), ('onion', 3)]
drinks = [('water', 1), ('juice', 2), ('soda', 3)]

options = fruits, veggies, drinks
possibles = product(*(combinations(opt, 2) for opt in options))
purchases = (list(chain.from_iterable(p)) for p in possibles)
within_range = [p for p in purchases if 12 <= sum(price for _, price in p) <= 14]
```

produces

```
>>> within_range[0]
[('apple', 1), ('banana', 2), ('tomato', 1), ('onion', 3), ('juice', 2), ('soda', 3)]
>>> within_range[-1]
[('banana', 2), ('orange', 3), ('cucumber', 2), ('onion', 3), ('water', 1), ('soda', 3)]
>>> [sum(p for _,p in w) for w in within_range]
[12, 12, 13, 12, 12, 13, 12, 13, 14, 12, 13, 12, 13, 14, 13, 14]
```